# iOS TabBarController background color

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, background-color

I have a tabbarcontroller that is pushed onto a navigationController. I tried to change the background color of the tab bar however it does not work:

```
    UIViewController *viewController1, *viewController2;
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        viewController1 = [[Tab1_iPhone alloc] initWithNibName:@"tab1_iPhone" bundle:nil];
        viewController2 = [[Tab2_iPhone alloc] initWithNibName:@"tab2_iPhone" bundle:nil]; 
    } 
    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 480, 48);
    UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [v setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]]; //003366
    [v setAlpha:1.0];
    [[self.tabBarController tabBar] insertSubview:v atIndex:0];


    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: viewController1, viewController2, nil];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.tabBarController animated:YES];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

This is the code I saw on a similar post that changes the bg color:

```
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 480, 48);
    UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [v setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]]; //003366
    [v setAlpha:1.0];
    [[self.tabBarController tabBar] insertSubview:v atIndex:0];
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: try addSubview, instead of insertSubview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below code helps you to add custom colors with RGB values to ur tabBar.

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar.tintColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0.00
                                                            green:0.62
                                                             blue:0.93
                                                            alpha:1.0];
```

Comment: This doesn't change background color, only color of the tab bar icons